# O que é Classe AsyncPostBackTrigger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Como devo usar e o que faz esse tipo de classe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define um controle e um evento opcional do controle como um gatilho de controle de `postback` `assíncrono` que faz o controle `UpdatePanel` ser atualizado. <sub>*Referencia*</sub> [Microsoft Developer Network - Classe AsyncPostBackTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger(v=vs.110).aspx).

Basicamente, quando se utiliza [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx), os controles contido nele tem suas informações atualizadas sem dar um `refresh` na página, mas, existe uma técnica que ao declarar um [AsyncPostBackTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) de algum controle fora do [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx) faça esse controle ter o mesmo comportamento dos que estão dentro do [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx).

Um ***exemplo*** seria a declaração dessa forma:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnDateTimeNowUpdate" 
                runat="server" 
                Text="Atualizar" 
                OnClick="BtnDateTimeNowUpdate_Click" />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnDateTimeNowUpdate" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblDateTimeNow" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

nesse simples código, observe que o botão `BtnDateTimeNowUpdate` está fora do [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx), mas, tem o mesmo comportamento de como se estivesse dentro dele pela simples configuração presente no [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnDateTimeNowUpdate" />
</Triggers>
```

se essa configuração não estivesse assim, esse botão daria um `refresh` na página inteira que é o comportamento normal para [WebForm](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_wbf.htm).

Pode ser utilizado, quando um controle fora do [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx), tenha que interagir com os controles dentro do [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx).

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Classe AsyncPostBackTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Introdução ao Controle UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [ASP .NET - Criando seu primeiro Web Forms](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_wbf.htm)